# Advanced routing in Symfony v3

Tags: php, symfony, routes, url-routing, symfony-3.4

I'm after a custom routing method so I can have below links to be handled by single controller action:

```
/q-query_term
/category-category_name/city-city_name/q-query_term
/city-city_name/category-category_name/q-query_term
/city-city_name/q-query_term
/category-category_name/q-query_term
/city-city_name
/category-category_name
```

Is it possible even possible? I don't use `SensioExtraBundle` so routes has to be written down in yaml.

For instance in Zend Framework 2 it is possible quite easily, because I can write a class, which would handle the routing as a wish. Don't know how to achieve the same in Symfony though, any help would be appreciated.

The only way I can come up with is to create a custom route loader, calculate all route permutations and return that collection, but don't know if it the best solution possible.

This question is unique, because I need to use single route name instead of specyfing tens of different route definitions.

Comment: Thank you for your input, but I've been there and that answers does not solve my question at all.

Comment: Can we know why you need a single route name or/and why you can't have route with `/q-Houses?city_name=NewYork` to understand the context

Comment: Would a catch-all route work for you? You could then do the processing inside the controller.

Comment: @goto because of SEO, ultimately I'd like to have urls like `/from-chicago/in-flats/find-room` or `/in-music/find-artist` etc.

Comment: @lxg I guess that would have to do, sound like a good idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple solution would be to define the route as catch-all …

```
# Resources/config/routing.yml

catch_all:
    path:  /{path}
    defaults: { _controller: FooBarBundle:Catchall:dispatcher, path : "" }
    requirements:
        path: ".*"
```

… and do all further processing in the controller:

```
# Controller/CatchallController.php

class CatchallController extends Controller
{
    public function dispatcherAction(Request $request, string $path)
    {
        if (/* path matches pattern 1 */)
            return $this->doQuery($request, $path);
        elseif (/* path matches pattern 2 */)
            return $this->doCategoryCityQuery($request, $path);

        // ... and so on

        else
            return new Response("Page not found", 404);
    }

    private function doQuery($request, $path)
    {
        // do stuff and return a Response object
    }

    private function doCategoryCityQuery($request, $path)
    {
        // do stuff and return a Response object
    }
}
```

Comment: That will have to do. Thanks! I'm really disapointed there's no such flexible way as ZF2/3 [has to offer](https://olegkrivtsov.github.io/using-zend-framework-3-book/html/en/Routing/Writing_Own_Route_Type.html).